# You have an error in your SQL syntax - XAMPP

Tags: php, sql

I've tried running a query but it says that I have an error in my SQL syntax. Why?

This should be the only code you need:

```
$sql = "INSERT (email, username, password) VALUES ($email, $username, $password)";
```

I am also aware of SQL injection. I will add a patch which is `mysqli_real_eacape_string()` function.

Comment: This should be the only answer you need: INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Comment: If you were really aware of SQL injection, you would use prepared statements - not escape the input.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the table name. Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (email, username, password) VALUES ($email, $username, $password)";
```

Comment: one big correction +1

Comment: this is only 50% of the problem. I can't see why this received so many upvotes. I honestly doubt that all of those values are integers.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I totally agree, I also think that the two links in duplicate section are not for 100% direct answers to the issue

Comment: *"I also think that the two links in duplicate section are not for 100% direct answers to the issue"* - @whitelettersinblankpapers I doubt that.